# set gnuplot precision for a specific column

Tags: gnuplot, precision

I have a data file with 3 columns and I'd like to plot a 2D map plot. What I do in gnuplot is:

p'datafile' u 1:2:3 with image

for some set of data, the data on the 3rd column (say Z) are different with order of 0.01, e.g 1.56, 1.58, 1.59 etc. I'd like to skip those small difference and consider them all 1.5. How can I set gnuplot to consider only up to one digit after decimal for 3rd column? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `floor` function to round your numbers down:

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:2:(floor($3*1e1)/1e1) with image
```

This sets all your numbers to 1 decimal place. If you wanted to do the same thing for a higher number of decimal places, you could change the `1e1` to `1eN`, where `N` is the number of decimal places you want.

Comment: Perfect! all what I wanted. Thanks