# matplotlib precision for a specific column

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot, color-mapping

I am plotting a scatter plot with the following part:

```
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

a = axes([.65, .6, .2, .2], axisbg='none')

sc=plt.scatter(x, y, c=z,s=500, marker='s',cmap=cm)

plt.colorbar(sc)

title('Density')
```

The z data sometimes happens to be very close to be homogeneous i.e 1.99,2.01,2.03,1.98 etc. This lead to a colorplot with different z value. How can I set them all to 2 e.g in a way that colormap will be flat?

here is the same issue that I had with gnuplot and I got this hint which solved the issue:

[set gnuplot precision for a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231375/set-gnuplot-precision-for-a-specific-column)

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to your other answer, it sounds like you want `numpy.round`.  Do you just want values near 2 to be rounded? E.g. `[1.99, 2.01, 5.01]` --> `[2.0, 2.0, 5.01]` Or do you want everything to be rounded? (if you want everything rounded just use `c=np.round(z)`)

Comment: I wanted to round them all, perfect! Just one issue: how to set colorbar label now just to be e.g 2.0?

Comment: Well, if they all have one value, why do you want a colorbar?  To set the colorbar label, use `cbar = plt.colorbar(sc); cbar.set_label('2')`.  However, it sounds like you might be better served by skipping `numpy.round` and instead doing `plt.scatter(..., vmin=0, vamx=4)` to set the min and max of the colorbar. Presumably you're comparing it to another dataset?